# Adding no value to return list

Tags: list, f#

I'm having a problem with understanding how F# works. I come from C# and I think that I'm trying to make F# work like C#. My biggest problem is returning values in the correct format.

Example:
Let's say I have function that takes a list of integers and an integer.
 Function should print a list of indexes where values from list match passed integer.

My code:

```
let indeks myList n = myList |> List.mapi (fun i x -> if x=n then i else 0);;
indeks [0..4] 3;;
```

However it returns:

```
val it : int list = [0; 0; 0; 3; 0]
```

instead of just [3] as I cannot ommit else in that statement.
Also I have targeted signature of -> int list -> int -> int list and I get something else.

Same goes for problem no. 2 where I want to provide an integer and print every number from 0 to this integer n times (where n is the iterated value):
example:
MultiplyValues 3;;
output: [1;2;2;3;3;3]

Best I could do was to create list of lists.

What am I missing when returning elements?
How do I add nothing to the return
example: if x=n then n else AddNothingToTheReturn

Comment: This is a good overview of the syntax: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/expressions-and-syntax.html

Comment: There are a LOT of functions in the List module, and often the problem you're trying to solve has already been solved for you, as with the `List.choose` and `List.collect` functions. But if you don't know they exist, it's hard to use them! Therefore, I recommend giving http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/ a read. And when you're done, read the rest of the series there. That site the best single resource I've found for learning F#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `List.choose`:

```
let indeks lst n =
    lst
    |> List.mapi (fun i s -> if s = n then Some i else None)
    |> List.choose id
```

Sorry, I didn't notice that you had a second problem too.  For that you can use `List.collect`:

```
let f (n : int) : list<int> =
    [1 .. n]
    |> List.collect (fun s -> List.init s (fun t -> s))
printfn "%A" (f 3) // [1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 3]
```

Please read [the documentation for List.collect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.collect['t,'u]-function-[fsharp]) for more information.

**EDIT**

Following `s952163`'s lead, here is another version of the first solution without the `Option` type:

```
let indeks (lst : list<int>) (n : int) : list<int> =
    lst
    |> List.fold (fun (s, t) u -> s + 1, (if u = n then (s :: t) else t)) (0, [])
    |> (snd >> List.rev)
```

This one traverses the original list once, and the (potentially much shorter) newly formed list once.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is quite idiomatic. Here's one solution that avoids the use of Option types and id:

```
let indeks2 lst n =
    lst
    |> List.mapi (fun i x -> (i,x))
    |> List.filter (fun x -> (fst x) % n = 0 ) 
    |> List.map snd
```

You can modify the filter function to match your needs.

If you plan to generate lots of sequences it might be a good idea to explore Sequence (list) comprehensions:

```
[for i in 1..10 do
    yield! List.replicate i i]
```

If statements are an expression in F# and they return a value. In this case both the IF and ELSE branch must return the same type of value. Using Some/None (Option type) gets around this. There are some cases where you can get away with just using If.